# iron-router data is not accessible inside JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

My template is rendering data OK without any problem, but if I try to access to it inside my JS script i get null or undefined... Here is my code

**iron-router**

```
@route 'responder',
    path: '/quesabesde/:_screenName'
    yieldTemplates:
      responderContent:
        to: "mainContent"
      responderHeader:
        to: "mainHeader"
    waitOn: ->
      @subscribe 'getPreguntas', @params._screenName
    data: ->
      Preguntas.findOne({owner: @params._screenName})
```

**Template script with NULL result**

```
Template.responderContent.rendered = ->
  console.log(@data)
```

**Template HTML WORKING**

```
{{#each level}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

And I get  `null` on console... but as I said my template is rendering it OK. I want to access data inside my script in order to set sessions and manipulate the data for other purposes

Comment: `@data` is looking in the template instance for the data, rather than the route.  Try `Router.current().data()` instead.

Comment: @richsilv it returns me "undefined". But if I delay it, I get the data object but that's not the purpose... `@data` is instant, sent from iron-router instantly when you access the page as it contains a mongo query done before everythng loads... It seems to be a bug with iron-routes because I can access `@data` if I hardcode it and remove the `waitOn` function... Which is weird

Comment: This is a documented (if often undesirable) phenomenon.  I would highly recommend reading [this](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/265), particularly from Nov 19 downwards.  Note that the easiest fix is just to have a loading template.

Comment: @richsilv Can you post it as an answer? It was PERFECT for me. using `action: ->
      @render() if @ready()` everything is working as intended :D

Comment: Glad to hear it, posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented (if often undesirable) phenomenon. I would highly recommend reading [this](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/265), particularly from Nov 19 downwards. Note that the easiest fix is just to have a loading template.